# How to solve the issue of i and j in character segmentation?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image]

I have a code for segmenting characters(english letters) from an image, the program does it well but the only problem is that when it comes to lower case letter "i" it segments it as two different objects 1 is the dot and the other is the remaining part of the letter "i" (same is the case with letter j) . My question is what should I do so that they are outputted as they are in the original image.

Code:

```
function charac(I)

bw = ~im2bw(I,0.99);

lc= bw(13:47,:);

uc= bw(90:123,:);

unknwn= bw(170:205,:);

l_alp = regionprops(lc,'Image');

u_alp = regionprops(uc,'Image');

unknown_alp = regionprops(unknwn,'Image');

for i = 1:length(l_alp)

l_alp(i).Image= norm_image_size(l_alp(i).Image, max(size(l_alp(i).Image)));

l_alp(i).Image= imresize(l_alp(i).Image, [40,40]);

end

for i = 1:length(u_alp)

u_alp(i).Image= norm_image_size(u_alp(i).Image, max(size(u_alp(i).Image)));

u_alp(i).Image= imresize(u_alp(i).Image, [40,40]);

end

for i = 1:length(unknown_alp)

unknown_alp(i).Image= norm_image_size(unknown_alp(i).Image, 

max(size(unknown_alp(i).Image)));

unknown_alp(i).Image= imresize(unknown_alp(i).Image, [40,40]);

end

alp = [u_alp;l_alp];

for j=1:length(unknown_alp)

for i=1:length(alp)

temp= alp(i).Image;

temp2= unknown_alp(j).Image;

D(i)= sum(abs(temp(:)- temp2(:)));

end

[m midx] = min(D);

subplot(1,2,1);

imshow(unknown_alp(j).Image);

subplot(1,2,2);

imshow(alp(midx).Image);

drawnow

pause(0.5)

end

end

function alp=norm_image_size(alp, maxS)

dif= maxS- size(alp)

 if rem(dif(1), 2)==0

  alp = padarray(alp, [dif(1)/2 0],'both');

 else

  alp = padarray(alp, [(dif(1)-1)/2 0],'both');

  alp = padarray(alp, [1 0],'post');

end

if rem(dif(2), 2)==0

  alp = padarray(alp, [0 dif(2)/2],'both');

 else

  alp = padarray(alp, [0 (dif(2)-1)/2],'both');

  alp = padarray(alp, [0 1],'post');

end

end
```

Here's what I get when I segment out the small `i`:

[image: The output for letter "i"]

Comment: This post is a misnomer.  You aren't "recognizing" any characters at all. You are **segmenting them**.  Character recognition is something like OCR where you infer what the actual character is given the image of it. This code is in no way a recognition algorithm. Your question is asking how to ensure that lowercase `i` and `j` have not only the main stroke but the diacritic dots (i.e. the dots above each character) recognized as single objects instead of separate ones.  Please consider editing your post so that you don't confuse people who legitimately want to answer your question.

Comment: OK, since that issue is fixed, can we assume that the text will always be horizontally aligned?... such as what we see in the image you have provided?  Will text ever be shown on an angle, or perhaps backwards... upside down?

Comment: The text will be aligned horizontally. I have attached an image of the output , kindly help me out with this. The problem is with these three lines i guess:                                                                                                    l_alp = regionprops(lc,'Image');
u_alp = regionprops(uc,'Image');
unknown_alp = regionprops(unknwn,'Image');

Comment: You can add an `imopen` before your `l_alp = regionprops(lc,'Image');`. It will add a small buffer to your image, so your i and j won't be separated.

Comment: Can you just guide me with the command for using imopen ? I'll be greatful

Comment: @SidraAminSiddiqui Again, do not vandalise or edit important information out of your post. This question is supposed to remain for other users to benefit from, for posterity. You are not permitted to significantly worsen or vandalize your own posts on StackOverflow, as you have irrevocably licensed the post and its content to StackExchange under the CC BY SA license upon posting.

Answer (score 2):

I added a small vertical buffer to your image in order to link the dot of the i to the rest of the letter.

Check the doc:

[imopen](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imopen.html)

[watershed](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/watershed.html)

With this method I perform the operation to whole image. I think you can adjust your code with this one.

```
I = imread('image.png');

bw = im2bw(I);

buffersize = 4;
se = strel('line',buffersize,90);
bwopen = imopen(bw,se); %add a small vertical buffer.

D = watershed(bwopen); %segmentation of your image

for i = 1:max(unique(D));
    letter = uint8(bw);
    letter(D~=i)=2;
    boundcol = find(max(letter==0,[],1));
    boundrow = find(max(letter==0,[],2));
    isol{i} = bw(boundrow(1):boundrow(end),boundcol(1):boundcol(end));
end

imshow(isol{1}) %show the first letter.
```

Limitation:

- It won't work with a bigger/smaller image, if you want to adjust the code for different image size you have to change the buffersize.

Result:

Step1:
[image: Step1]
Step2:
[image: Step2]
Step3:

[image: Example: j]

Comment: @obchardon sir that works perfectly fine but the problem is I need to output it in another manner. If you will run the code I have provided you'll come to know , its like the output contains two images one is the original image and the other is the segmented image and after few seconds the other character is displayed.

Comment: @SidraAminSiddiqui I don't really understand your problem. You can just take my code and use the `boundcol`and `boundrow` to isolate the letter in the original image. Then use the part of your code with the two subplot and drawnow to plot the result. The problem was to isolate correctly the 'i' and 'j' and for me this problem is resolved. @rayryeng thanks :)

Comment: @obchardon yes sir I did that and it works perfectly fine thank you :)